# How to check if a certain numerical value is above 20% in a atomic vector

Tags: r

I have a atomic vector and want to filter out all the rows that scores above 20%.
The data looks as follows:

```
                 Gain
ch1_500001  0.0000000
ch1_1500001 0.0000000
ch1_2500001 0.3157895
ch1_3500001 0.1578947
ch1_4500001 0.1578947
ch1_5500001 0.1578947
```

So i want ch1_2500001 to be selected.

I've tried several options:

`freqsnormg<- freqsnorm==0.20`  gives only FALSE

`freqsnormg<- freqsnorm[,1]==0.20` gives only FALSE

How to get a new table that holds only the values above the 20%. And do not changes the values in a logical.

Comment: Note that that's not an atomic vector- it looks like a data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the values above 20%

```
freqsnormg<- freqsnorm[freqsnorm[,1]>0.20, ]
```

to see the values below 20%

```
freqsnormg<- freqsnorm[freqsnorm[,1]<0.20, ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer :) it helps me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't really make sense, you mention the word vector, then show a data frame.

1. If you want to filter out values of a **vector** called `freqsnorm` then:

   ```
   freqsnorm[freqsnorm < 0.20]
   ```
2. Your data looks like a **data frame**, so you need a comma to select on rows:

   ```
   ##Here freqsnorm[,1] selects the first column
   freqsnorm[freqsnorm[,1] < 0.20]
   ##Refer to the column by name
   freqsnorm[freqsnorm$Gain < 0.20]
   ```

In both cases, the part in the square brackets will give you a vector of logicals, i.e.:

```
freqsnorm$Gain < 0.20
```

will return TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, etc. We then use the square brackets to select the elements we want.

Comment: Yeah i mentioned the word vector because that was the error i was experiencing, it said Error in freqsnorm$gain : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. So that was why i was thinking it was not a data frame. But many thanks for the explanation and helping me.

Comment: `freqsnorm$gain` is a vector, but `freqsnorm` is a data frame.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with `data.frame` try:

```
freqsnormg <- read.table(text='                 Gain
ch1_500001  0.0000000
ch1_1500001 0.0000000
ch1_2500001 0.3157895
ch1_3500001 0.1578947
ch1_4500001 0.1578947
ch1_5500001 0.1578947', header=T)

subset(freqsnormg, Gain>.2)  # above 20%
                 Gain
ch1_2500001 0.3157895

subset(freqsnormg, Gain<.2)  # below 20%
                 Gain
ch1_500001  0.0000000
ch1_1500001 0.0000000
ch1_3500001 0.1578947
ch1_4500001 0.1578947
ch1_5500001 0.1578947
```

Comment: It does not work like this. The best option for me seems to be:
freqsnormg<- freqsnorm[freqsnorm[,1]>0.20, ]

Comment: @Sanshine It does work, see my edit and also see Gavin Simpson answer. If you have a data.frame my answer does work.

Comment: thanks for the explanation i will try both options provided by you and David Robinson. And see which is faster.

Answer (score 1):

The data you show is **not** an atomic vector (component `Gain` most likely *is* an atomic vector but the full object isn't).

One option is to use `subset()`. Using your data

```
df <- read.table(text = "                 Gain
ch1_500001  0.0000000
ch1_1500001 0.0000000
ch1_2500001 0.3157895
ch1_3500001 0.1578947
ch1_4500001 0.1578947
ch1_5500001 0.1578947", header = TRUE)
```

We have

```
> subset(df, Gain > 0.2)
                 Gain
ch1_2500001 0.3157895
```

If you want to force this to drop to a vector (i.e. loose the empty dimension) then

```
> subset(df, Gain > 0.2)[,1]
[1] 0.3157895
```